# Generate a SSRS report in default browser from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have a VB.NET solution that stores data to a SQL database.  I have written the first of several SSRS reports.  Now I want to generate the reports from my VB.NET solution.

I have a subroutine that will generate the report,

```
Public Shared Sub GenerateReport(ByVal RptName As String, ByVal ParamArray Params() As Object)
    Dim strPath As String = sqlSSRS + Replace(RptName, " ", "%20")
    Dim _class As cParameters

    'strPath += "&rc:Parameters=false&rs:Command=Render"
    'strPath += "&rs:Command=Render"
    For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(Params)
        _class = DirectCast(Params(i), cParameters)
        strPath += "&" & _class.ParamName & "=" & _class.Value
    Next
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strPath)
End Sub
```

If I generate a path with no parameters the report will open in the default browser. So this works...

```
http://sqlServerName:80/Reports/report/ToolCrib/Toolbox%20by%20Installer
```

But neither this ...

```
http://sqlServerName:80/Reports/report/ToolCrib/Toolbox%20by%20Installer&@UserID=7&@ProjectID=20026&@ToolboxID=10&@ToolStatus=2
or this
http://sqlServerName:80/Reports/report/ToolCrib/Toolbox%20by%20Installer&UserID=7&ProjectID=20026&ToolboxID=10&ToolStatus=2
```

does.
I obviously have an issue passing parameters.  In one case I don't need them but in other cases I want to provide them, which is why I wrote the GenerateReport routine with the optional Parameter array.  Here is the error message I get which I know from past experience is sort of a catch all when MS doesn't "know" how else to classify an SSRS error.

The path of the item '/ToolCrib/Toolbox by Installer&UserID=7&ProjectID=20026&ToolboxID=10&ToolStatus=2' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You path needs to use `reportserver?` instead of `Reports/report` when using parameters.

Try

```
http://sqlServerName:80/reportserver?/ToolCrib/Toolbox%20by%20Installer&UserID=7&ProjectID=20026&ToolboxID=10&ToolStatus=2
```

You could add a REPLACE:

```
strPath = Replace(strPath, "/Reports/report/", "/reportserver?/")
```

For more reading, you can check out

[MS Docs url-access-parameter-reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-parameter-reference?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Working with a new language is sure humbling.  That fixed it thanks.